# MoonAPNS. Error processing certificate. Impossible to call to SSPI

Tags: asp.net, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a chat that uses APNS.

To do that I'm using MoonAPNS wrapper in C#.

I've developed an ASP web service that uses this dll.

I've followed all the steps in the [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2) where I found the code.

I'm using the notification over an app with development sign.

I've been debugging and in the method: SendQueueToapple in this line:

```
_apnsStream.BeginRead(response, 0, 6, ReadResponse, new MyAsyncInfo(response, _apnsStream));
```

I'm getting this error:

InnerException:
Unknown error processing certificate.
-2146893017

I've reviewed the certificate, the device token and everything is ok according with the tutorial, but I'm still getting this error.

Anyone has idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will be helpful after 2 years, but I leave the answer for iOS8.

Apple has changed the server security, you have to change from SSL to TLS:

Original code:

```
_apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host,certificates,System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
```

New code:

```
_apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host,certificates,System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);
```

I hope this information is helpful to someone.

Someone commented this in the GIT forum